# Add dataset issue in ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net + SQL Server 2008 Enterprise to develop a simple web application.

In MSDN library topic "Walkthrough: Using a Database Data Source with the ReportViewer Web Server Control in Local Processing Mode", which is located in the following Url, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252123.aspx

I am following the steps in section "Define a data connection and DataTable by adding a DataSet", step 2, which says,

**In the Add New Item dialog box, select DataSet and click Add. When prompted if you should add the item to the App_Code folder, click Yes.**

My question is when I click add for a data source, the DataSet1.xsd is added directly into my project, no additional prompted to ask if I should add this item to App_Code folder.

Anything wrong?

BTW: I am working under an ASP.Net application, not a web site type project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> BTW: I am working under an ASP.Net
>   application, not a web site type
>   project.

I think that is the reason why you don't see that prompt message. For a `Website` project, every code file should go into `App_Code` folder but for a `Web Application` project, that is not the case.

Comment: So, you think there is no issue in my environment?

Comment: No, your environment is completely fine, it's just you can place your code files anywhere in your project while working on a `Web Application` project.